# dc.js - how to get chart.chartGroup to put the chart in the group

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

I am looking for using chartGroup attribute of dc.js with dc.redrawAll(groupName).

I am not able to find any example for this I tried as follow

```
chart
.chartGroup("group1")
.height(ht)
.dimension(dim)
.group(grp)


dc.redrawAll("group1")
```

E.g. in following js fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Bra2H/72/
in filter1 funcition 
If I try

```
dc.redrawAll("group1");
//dc.redrawAll();
```

It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I got it

http://jsfiddle.net/Bra2H/73/

So I have to explicitly called dc.registerChart to associate group

```
dc.registerChart(hitslineChart,"group1")
```

It did the trick.

Comment: That is very strange behavior.  If you set the chartGroup in the constructor or using `.anchor()`, it will register the chart, but actually setting `.chartGroup()` will not.  I have created an issue: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/775